# Simple inner join with django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I'm beginning with Django and I've got what I think is a simple question. How can I obtain the result of the next query with QuerySet?

```
select * 
from poll p,
     choice c 
where p.id = c.poll_id
```

I've find two approaches:

```
Poll.objects.filter(id__in = Choice.objects.values_list('poll_id'))
```

and

```
Poll.objects.filter(choice__id__isnull = False).distinct()
```

but both of them seem to me very complex. Is it there a simple way to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, your second option is what I would go for `Poll.objects.filter(choice__isnull = False).distinct()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it's much prettier too

Answer (score 0):

```
p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)

p.choice_set.all()
```

Comment: This code brings me all choices of a poll, not all polls with choices.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

From Django 1.4 on, you may use `prefetch_related` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)):

```
all_polls = Poll.objects.all().prefetch_related('choice_set')
for poll in all_polls:
    # This will list all choices of this poll
    choices = poll.choice_set.all()
```

Django will make a total of 2 queries: one for the polls and one for the choices.